# How to SQL select excluding strings with N duplicate characters in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

How to make a select from a table excluding rows with N duplicate characters in a row in a certain column? Let's say N=5

```
'0000011114BR13471' // Exclude
'554XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // Exclude
'000111114BR134716' // Exclude
'000011114BR134716' // Include
'11880000000000000' // Exclude
'12345678901200000' // Exclude
'12345678901200001' // Include
```

I tried many combinations but none of them worked. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE not (mycolumn regexp '(.)\1{5,}');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` to match regular Expression and `EXCEPT` clause to exclude unwanted Results. A query like this might work

**In SQL SERVER**

```
Select * from myTable
EXCEPT 
Select * from myTable WHERE ColumnName like '(.)\1{4,}'
```

**In MySQl**

```
Select * from myTable 
where ColumnName Not In( 
Select ColumnName from myTable WHERE ColumnName RLIKE '(.)\1{4,}')
```

Here N=5. the 4 in regular expration represents 5 duplicates.

Comment: This answer is OK provided you only want unique results.
If you have any duplicate values that should be returned, that will only be returned once.

Comment: Is it possible to give an explanation of the syntax of this regular expression? AFAIK `'(.)\1{4,}'` matches an opening brace '(' followed by a random character '.', a closing brace ')' ...... . And I do not see any '(' or ')' in the things that need a match?

Comment: (1) (.) matches any character (except for line terminators)

(2) \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

(3) {4,} matches the previous token between 4 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

https://regex101.com/r/eR9kQ6/1 you can check the details of regex here

Comment: You are probably confusing `LIKE` with `RLIKE` ?

Comment: Yes My Mistake I only considered SQL SERVER and not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MySQL supports back-references in regular expressions -- which is a shame for your problem.  One method is brute force:

```
select t.*
from t
where col not regexp '0{5}|1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5}|6{5}|7{5}|8{5}|9{5}|X{5}';
```

Another method is a recursive CTE, which breaks up the string into individual characters and then uses window functions to determine if there are 5 in a row:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select col,left(col, 1) as chr, substr(col, 2) as rest, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select col, left(rest, 1), substr(rest, 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select col
from (select cte.*,
             lead(lev, 4) over (partition by col, chr order by lev) as chr_4
      from cte
     ) x
group by col
having max(chr_4 = lev + 4) = 0
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=151574f66b3b8aed81041d0eb589e29c) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0:

```
mycolumn regexp '(.)\\1{4}'
```

Notes:

- Two backslashes are needed.
- Since there is 1 selected (`.`), you need to check for only 4 more, not 5.
- The `,` (meaning "or more") is unnecessary.